# Необходимо автоматизировать нажатие Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, bash

На моём VDS сервере я сканирую диапазон ip адресов но бывает такое что некоторые адреса вызывают проблему и программа останавливается и вывод какой либо информации в консоль прекращается, в таком случае для того чтобы перейти к следующему адресу необходимо нажать Ctrl+C. Возможно ли написать bash-скрипт который в такой ситуации пропустит проблемный адрес?

Comment: kill на команду в цикле

Answer (score 5):

Уже написали что `Ctrl+C`, отправляет сигнал `SIGINT`, код сигнала `2`
(`kill -l` - возможные сигналы)

Для автоматизации ожидания определенного времени в командах в которых это не предусмотрено существует команда `timeout` которая по истечению указанного времени отправит нужный сигнал запущенному процессу.
Синтаксис такой:

```bsh
timeout -s<сигнал> <время ожидания выполнения> <Команда>
```

Для примера:

```bsh
#Гарантированно будет отправлен сигнал SIGINT, так как установлено врем ожидания 3, на команду sleep ожидающую 5 секунд
timeout -s2 3 sleep 5
...
```

Проверить что команда завершилась по истечению таймаута можно через код возврата, по умолчанию он будет равен 124

```
...
[ $? -eq 124 ] && { echo "Процесс завершился по таймауту"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl-C` посылает процессу сигнал `SIGINT`, так что программно это можно сделать так:

```
kill -SIGINT $PID
```

Тут `$PID` - идентификатор процесса.